# Assigning values received from asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, asynchronous

So I'm creating the a FB app that uses the FB SDK. In the code below, I am getting a list of movies I like and their FB page ids in 'data'. Then, I'm iterating through it to get the get the names of the movies and using the page ids, i get their page links and src of their page profile pictures. Then I use the details to create the following HTML block:

```
<article>
<figure>
    <img src="source">
</figure>
<div>
    <a href="link"/>
</div>
</article>
```

So, I dynamically create each article block and then append them to the below HTML code:

```
<body>

 <header></header>

 <section>
     <article></article>
 </section>

 <footer></footer>

 <script src = *source of my .js file*></script>

</body>
```

This is my js code:

```
// data has a list of FB movie pages, each containing the name of the movie and page id
function print(data)
{
//iterates through the object passed to print movie names in console.  

var target = document.querySelector('article');
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        var temp = data[i];
        var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
        var linkText = document.createTextNode(temp["name"]);
        linkElement.appendChild(linkText);

        //getting the link to the movie's FB page
        getLink(function(response){linkElement.href = response;},temp["id"]);

        var imgElement = document.createElement('img');

        //getting the src of the picture of the movie's page
        getPic(function(response){imgElement.setAttribute("src", response);},temp["id"]);

        imgElement.setAttribute("width", "304");
        imgElement.setAttribute("height", "228");
        imgElement.setAttribute("alt", temp["name"]);

        var article = document.createElement("article"),
            figure = document.createElement("figure"),
            div = document.createElement("div");

        div.appendChild(linkElement);
        figure.appendChild(imgElement);
        article.appendChild(figure);
        article.appendChild(div);
        console.log(article);
        docFrag.appendChild(article);
    }
    target.appendChild(docFrag);
}

function getLink(callback,id)
{
   FB.api('/'+id+'?fields=link', function(response)
   {
       callback(response.link);
   });
}
function getPic(callback,id)
{
   FB.api('/'+id+'?fields=cover{source}', function(response)
       {
      callback(response.cover.source);
  });
}
```

My problem is that when I print the output, all the article blocks except the last one lose the href's and the src's for the 'img' blocks. When I print the articles in the console, the href and the src are empty except the last one. I think maybe it's got something to do with async calls to the FB SDK, but I'm not sure. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var` has function scope, not block scope, and is hoisted. Use `const` or `let` instead, *especially* in for loops, *especially* in asynchronous `for` loops:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const temp = data[i];
  const linkElement = document.createElement('a');
```

To the interpreter, what you're currently doing looks something like this:

```
function print(data) {
var target;
var docFrag; 
var temp;
var linkElement;
// etc
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  temp = data[i];
  linkElement = document.createElement('a');
  // etc
```

So after the end of the loop, once the responses come back, each callback is referencing the same `imgElement`, the last one the `for` loop reassigned.

You can also use `forEach`, which is significantly better than `for` loops in most respects. (no manual iteration, automatic abstraction, accepts functions as arguments)

```
data.forEach((temp) => {
  const linkElement = document.createElement('a');
  // ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!